# Todo list wont refresh after pushing to array

Tags: javascript

Whenever I add a todo to my array, it's not being refreshed in html, what do I need to sort this out? Also, how can I connect the Delete button which is being created in loop to a function?

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const btnAdd = document.querySelector('button')
let ul = document.querySelector('ul')

let todos = ["one", "two", "three"];


pushTodos = (e) => {

e.preventDefault();
todos.push(input.value);
input.value = '';
console.log(todos);
}


for(let i of todos) {
createList = document.createElement("li");
createList.innerHTML+=i + '<button>Delete</delete>';
    console.log(todos);
ul.appendChild(createList);
}

form.addEventListener('submit', pushTodos)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you only update DOM only once on document load. You don't do anything after updating the list. To fix this, create a sync function to synchronize your memory with the DOM and call it every time you update the list:

```
let todos = ["one", "two", "three"];

const syncTodosWithDOM = () => {
  ul.innerHTML = "";
  for (let i of todos) {
    createList = document.createElement("li");
    createList.innerHTML+=i + '<button>Delete</delete>';
    console.log(todos);
    ul.appendChild(createList);
  }
};

pushTodos = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  todos.push(input.value);
  input.value = '';
  console.log(todos);
  syncTodosWithDOM();
}
syncTodosWithDOM();
form.addEventListener('submit', pushTodos)
```

Comment: Thanks, also is it possible somehow to connect the delete button to a function?

Comment: @debooger3 Just remove items from the `todos` list and then call `syncTodosWithDOM` like in the example I provided. Also if my answer helped you, you can mark it as correct.

Comment: I mean how do I attach seperate function for the delete button, like `button.addEventlistener("click" ())`

Comment: @debooger3 Give your button an id and then use `querySelect` to get that element using that id: `document.querySelector("#button-id").addEventListener("click", (event) => { console.log("Clicked on a button!") });`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate `todos` inside `pushTodos` function. Create a separate function `createDomElem` which will create dom element and call this function again when the element is pushed in the array

```js
pushTodos = (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();
  todos.push(input.value);
  input.value = '';
  console.log(todos);
  createDomElem()
}

createDomElem = () => {
  for (let i of todos) {
    createList = document.createElement("li");
    createList.innerHTML += i + '<button>Delete</delete>';
    console.log(todos);
    ul.innerHTML = ''; // remove previous list
    ul.appendChild(createList);
  }

}
createDomElem() // will create initial list of todos
```

Answer (score 0):

In `pushTodos` you also need to refresh HTML.

```js
pushTodos = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  todos.push(input.value);
  input.value = '';

  createList = document.createElement("li");
  createList.innerHTML+=input.value + '<button>Delete</delete>';
  ul.appendChild(createList);
}
```